# Sending mails in Message Driven Bean

Tags: sendmail, message-driven-bean

I'm completely new with `javamail` and I would like to know if it is the right approach to send mail from inside an `MDB` in a Java EE application.

My purpose is simply to send asynchronous mail after a user has registered (only 1 mail at a time).

Also, I would like to know if `javamail` is efficient enough to fire more than 500 mails at a time (select all mail addresses from a DB to send a newsletter for example)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use javamail to send mail from an MDB. It's also efficient enough.